# Authorize.net Java example

Tags: java, authorize.net

I am looking to develop simple Java program which will be sending a request and get response from "Authorize.net" say for Authorization, Capture, Void, Refund Transactions etc. I have created my test account in authorized.net - https://sandbox.authorize.net/. I did goggled lots of week and didn't find any sample example for reference.

I am using AIM for my development, let's say I've code for AuthTransaction

```
GenericValue cc = (GenericValue) params.get("creditCard");
        String currency = (String) params.get("currency");
        String amount = ((BigDecimal)params.get("processAmount")).toString();
        String number = UtilFormatOut.checkNull(cc.getString("cardNumber"));
        String expDate = UtilFormatOut.checkNull(cc.getString("expireDate"));
        String cardSecurityCode = (String) params.get("cardSecurityCode");
        AIMRequest.put("x_Amount", amount);
        AIMRequest.put("x_Currency_Code", currency);        
        AIMRequest.put("x_Method", props.getProperty("method"));
        AIMRequest.put("x_Type", props.getProperty("transType"));
        AIMRequest.put("x_Card_Num", number);
        AIMRequest.put("x_Exp_Date", expDate);
        if (UtilValidate.isNotEmpty(cardSecurityCode)) {
            AIMRequest.put("x_card_code", cardSecurityCode);
        }
        if (AIMRequest.get("x_market_type") != null) {
            AIMRequest.put("x_card_type", getCardType(UtilFormatOut.checkNull(cc.getString("cardType"))));
        }
```

But I don't know how to make a request call and get a response back. Any one please guide me / provide me sample code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Authorize.net does provide Java SDK and maven dependency from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.authorize/anet-java-sdk.

Authorize.Net SDK includes standard payments, recurring billing, and customer profiles.

I've perform the simple AuthCapture Transaction through following Java code

```
package com.auth.net;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import net.authorize.Environment;
import net.authorize.Merchant;
import net.authorize.TransactionType;
import net.authorize.aim.Result;
import net.authorize.aim.Transaction;
import net.authorize.data.creditcard.CreditCard;

public class AIMauthCaptureTransactionDemo {
    public static final String apiLoginID= "Your Sandbox API Login ID";
    public static final String transactionKey= "Your Sandbox API Transaction Key";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Merchant merchant = Merchant.createMerchant(Environment.SANDBOX, apiLoginID, transactionKey);
        // create credit card
        CreditCard creditCard = CreditCard.createCreditCard();
        creditCard.setCreditCardNumber("4111 1111 1111 1111");
        creditCard.setExpirationMonth("12");
        creditCard.setExpirationYear("2018");

        // create transaction
        Transaction authCaptureTransaction = merchant.createAIMTransaction
                (TransactionType.AUTH_CAPTURE, new BigDecimal("5.00"));

        authCaptureTransaction.setCreditCard(creditCard);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Result<Transaction> result = (Result<Transaction>)merchant.postTransaction(authCaptureTransaction);

        if(result.isApproved()) {
            System.out.println("Response Code : "+ result.getReasonResponseCode());
            System.out.println("Response Text : " + result.getResponseText());
            System.out.println("Transaction Id: " + result.getTarget().getTransactionId());
            System.out.println("AuthorizationCode : "+result.getTarget().getAuthorizationCode());
        } 
        else if (result.isDeclined()) {
            System.out.println(result.getReasonResponseCode() + " : " + result.getResponseText());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(result.getReasonResponseCode() + " : " + result.getResponseText());
        }
    }

}
```

Here, Please refer first transaction which I performed some time before in below screen shot

[image]

Comment: How do we send the customer Zip code with code above? Do you need a Customer Profile?